# Rename nested field in BsonDocument with MongoDB.Driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a document, it contains a CustomFields document, in which there are still documents.

How to correctly update the `Checkpoint Comment` document name to the `Checkpoint Comment-test`.

I tried as below but it doesn't work.

```cs
var filter = Builders<Visit>.Filter;

UpdateDefinition<Visit> update = Builders<Visit>.Update.Rename(x => x.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == "Сheckpoint Comment").Name, "Сheckpoint Comment-test");
Collection.UpdateMany(filter.Where(x => true), update);
```

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("61e5707d23516865481ebee7"),
  "CustomFields": {
    "Сheckpoint Comment": {
      "FieldId": ObjectId("6149d5de44175b8324482904"),
      "Type": "Text",
      "ValueBson": "test"
    },
    "Time of arrival at the checkpoint": {
      "FieldId": ObjectId("6149d5de44175b8324482905"),
      "Type": "DateTime",
      "ValueBson": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solutions

**Solution 1**

If you apply `[BsonElement]` attribute to the class' property as below:

```cs
public class Visit
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public CustomField CustomFields { get; set; }
}

public class CustomField
{
    [BsonElement("Сheckpoint Comment")]
    public BsonProp Checkpoint { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Time of arrival at the checkpoint")]
    public BsonProp Time { get; set; }
}

public class BsonProp
{
   public ObjectId FieldId { get; set; }
   public string Type { get; set; }
   public string ValueBson { get; set; }
}
```

Then specify your field to be renamed as:

```cs
UpdateDefinition<Visit> update = Builders<Visit>.Update.Rename(x => x.CustomFields.Checkpoint, "CustomFields.Сheckpoint Comment-test");
Collection.UpdateMany(filter.Empty, update);
```

---

**Solution 2**

Without applying `[BsonElement]` attribute, just specify the field to be renamed in `string`.

```cs
UpdateDefinition<Visit> update = Builders<Visit>.Update.Rename("CustomFields.Сheckpoint Comment", "CustomFields.Сheckpoint Comment-test");
Collection.UpdateMany(filter.Empty, update);
```

---

### Concern & Suggestion

1. The field after rename needs with prefix `CustomFields.` as `"CustomFields.Сheckpoint Comment-test"` because you are updating the nested field in an object. Without the prefix `CustomFields.`, `Сheckpoint Comment-test` will be at the same level as `CustomFields`, but not inside the `CustomFields` object.
2. The `filter` with

```cs
filter.Where(x => true)
```

can be replaced with

```cs
filter.Empty
```

as they are equivalent. (As the first one forces the filter condition definitely true, while the second one applies no filter condition).